# TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Tags: python, linux

```
#!/usr/bin/python 

import time 
from array import *

THINKING  = 0
HUNGRY = 1
EATING = 2

class Philosopher: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.ph = array('i',[1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
        self.sleeptime = array('i',[30, 30, 30, 30, 30])

    def initialization_code(self):
        for i in range(self.ph.__len__()):
            self.ph[i] = THINKING

    def pickup(self,i):
        self.ph[i] = HUNGRY 
        self.test(i)
        if(EATING not in (self.ph[i])):
            while(EATING not in (self.ph[i])):
                time.sleep(self.sleeptime[i])

    def putdown(self,i):
        self.ph[i] = THINKING
        self.test((i+4)%5)
        self.test((i+1)%5)

    def test(self,i):
        if((2 not in (self.ph[(i+4)%5]))and(2 not in (self.ph[(i+1)%5]))and(self.ph[i]==HUNGRY)):
            self.ph[i] = EATING

    def start_process(self):
        for i in range(self.ph.__len__()):
            self.pickup(i)
            self.putdown(i)


    def display_status(self):
        for i in range(self.ph.__len__()):
            if (self.ph[i] == 0):
                print "%d is THINKING" % i+1
            elif (self.ph[i] == 1):
                print "%d is WAITING" % i+1
            elif (self.ph[i] == 2):
                print "%d is EATING" % i+1

phil = Philosopher()
phil.initialization_code()
phil.start_process()
phil.display_status()
```

The above is my piece of code in which i'm trying to implement dining philosopher problem in python.
when i run this code it shows me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "dining.py", line 59, in <module>

phil.start_process()

   File "dining.py", line 43, in start_process    
   self.pickup(i)    
   File "dining.py", line 27, in pickup    
   self.test(i)    
   File "dining.py", line 38, in test    
   if((2 not in (self.ph[(i+4)%5]))and(2 not in (self.ph[(i+1)%5]))and(self.ph[i]==HUNGRY)):
   TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Can anyone please help me at this, why is it showing this error. I searched about it but couldn't resolve.
   Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 6):

Your equations result in integers. You can't use `in` on integers.

```
>>> 'foo' in 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides the problem with `in`, which only can applied to iterables and to objects having `__contains__` in its class definition, you probably are going to run into the next problem: You don't have parallelization. So you either should use threads or replace the

```
if(EATING not in (self.ph[i])):
    while(EATING not in (self.ph[i])):
        time.sleep(self.sleeptime[i])
```

lines - which are an endless loop, because no one sets the `EATING` status.

Or you should do the timing by other means, by constantly checking wall clock time or by creating an event scheduling system which takes care of the actions which have to be done.

BTW: The `print "%d is THINKING" % i+1` are broken as well, because there are no `()` around the `i+1` and `%` has higher precedence.

Comment: Besides, why `self.ph.__len__()` instead of `len(self.ph)`?

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have already come across this mistake and the solution is running fine now

Answer (score 1):

I think you are generally using:

```
in / not in
```

incorrectly. It looks like you are trying to compare integers which should be done with

```
==
!=
>
>=
<
<=
```

operators instead.